# what is the meaning of rospack profile

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it to check the zombie file marked with * which ROS cannot use?

Then, what about those without * ?

```
 root@ShawnVM:~# rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.032583 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.025500   /opt/ros/indigo/share
0.005273   /root/catkin_ws/src
0.002334   /root/catkin_ws/src/rbx2
0.001137   /root/catkin_ws/src/rbx1
0.000451 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
0.000345   /root/catkin_ws/src/roberta-ros
0.000265 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core
0.000179 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/man
0.000111 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild
0.000064 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/doc
0.000020 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/man/man1
0.000019 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/config
0.000013 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin
0.000009 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/ros/core/rosbuild/tests
0.000005 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/doc/liborocos-kdl
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247701/what-is-the-meaning-of-rospack-profile/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The main function of rospack is to
> crawl through the packages in ROS_ROOT
> and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, read and parse
> the manifest.xml for each package, and
> assemble a complete dependency tree
> for all packages.

And more specifically for `rospack profile`:

> rospack’s performance can be
> adversely affected by the presence of
> very broad and/or deep directory
> structures that don’t contain manifest
> files. If such directories are in
> rospack’s search path, it can spend a
> lot of time crawling them only to
> discover that there are no packages to
> be found. You can prevent this latency
> by creating a rospack_nosubdirs file
> in such directories. If rospack seems
> to be running annoyingly slowly, you
> can use the profile command, which
> will print out the 20 slowest trees to
> crawl (or use profile --length=N to
> print the slowest N trees).

So the directories *without* *'s are the ones that contain packages.

This can all easily be found at the [rospack documentation](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/rospack.html)

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4